# How to collect system information in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, cpu, system-information

As System.Management is not implemented in Mono, so what is the way of getting system information in Mono? The information I am looking for is as follows:

1. CPU - Number of Processors, Processor Type, Model Number, Cores, Native Thread, Clock Speed, Manufacturer, Endianness, SSE Info
2. GPU - Model Number, Manufacturer, Number of CUDA Cores
3. Memory - Total RAM, Page Size
4. OS - Basic OS info

These information can be obtained via System.Management but only for .net/Windows. But if I try to run the same code on Mono/Linux, it will fail as System.Management is not implemented in Mono. So how can I get these information uniformly in an OS independent way?

Comment: "I am looking for a library which will..." SO expects: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "  Regarding GPU information, there are various ways to access the data you are looking for, and they don't require CUDA.  If you need help with that, pose a separate question that deals with that (and not mono).  Removing CUDA tag.  Voting to close.

Comment: Could anyone please care to explain me, how asking about the proper platform independent replacement of **System.Management** library has become a question to recommend a tool and hence off-topic in SO? System.Management library is a standard library in .net platform but in Mono it is not implemented. So there is no way to use this library in a .net application which will run in linux as well. I am just looking for a **Viable Alternative** to System.Management, not expert opinion.

Comment: I made it clear that I was focusing on your statement "I am looking for a library", by placing that *first* in my explanation for my vote.  So no, I don't intend to provide any explanation about how this is a question to recommend a tool.  You specifically asked for a library.  SO specifically has concerns about people asking for libraries (I didn't make any of this up myself).  Perhaps rather than getting upset about a question closure, you should just re-phrase the question to avoid the concern that I specifically identified.  I am just one vote. It seems others saw the same concern as well.

Comment: OK, as you have pointed out, I have edited my question as per your concern. Let me know if this question still sounds off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Simple try:

Try to use the "Environment" [members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx). May you have access to some of them.